# Servlet returns 404 error and throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestAttributeListener

Tags: eclipse, servlets

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestAttributeListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
```

i try to run a default program of hello world when i try to run the server it gives 'http:404 page not found' error and in console it gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestAttributeListener" i am a newbie in this framework so i tried my best but i wasn't able to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are your dependencies? Do you have a pom.xml? What version of Java EE/Jakarta EE are you using? What version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: What exactly is in your build path? Are you using Java EE or Jakarta EE? Which versions?

Comment: i am using java ee @dan1st

Comment: Tomcat 10 uses Jakarta EE. Try either updating to Jakarta EE 9 (or later) or downgrading Tomcat.

Comment: thans, but where can i upgrade to jakarta ee

Comment: change your dependencies. For example, if you are depending on `javax.servlet`, you should change that to `jakarta.servlet`.

Comment: bro i just checked that the 'servlet-api.jar' file has 'jakarta.servlet' and etc files however i couldn't find from where i can change tthe dependencies.
sorry

Comment: and that  'servlet-api.jar' is located under "java resources/libraries/server-runtime[appache tomcat 10.1]"

Comment: The original duplicate was horribly unhelpful. The current duplicates contain the real answers you're looking for. In the future don't use [java] tag when problem is not demonstrable using a plain Java application class with a main() method. It's then not necessarily properly understood by [java] experts.

Comment: ok i will thanks for the guidance @BalusC